# Creep: переклад

Tags: переклад

У Radiohead є чудова пісня "Creep".
В цій пісні є рядок:
"But I'm a creep, I'm a weirdo".

Як його правильно перекласти українською? Одне слово "creep" має дуже багато варіантів перекладу: витися, заповзати, лазити, прислужуватися, здригатися, ледь пересуватися, стелитися, крастися, підкрадатися, плазувати, повзати, повзти, гадина, лаз для худоби, повзучість, повільний рух.

"I'm a weirdo" - "я дивак", якщо я правильно переклала. А от з "creep" не зовсім зрозуміло.

Comment: Знов-таки, чим не підходять ті (численні) значення, які ви знайшли? Контекст має бути таким, як у тексті пісні чи якимось іншим? Це все важливо.

Comment: @bytebuster Питання про те, як перекласти рядок з пісні. Жоден з наведених перекладів не відповідає контексту, тобто не пасує до слова «дивак».

Answer (score 1):

У цьому випадку «creep» – це людина, яка викликає огиду, страх, або занепокоєння. Отже можна перекласти як страховище або огидник. Инші можливі варіянти: мерзотник, паскудник, поганець. Але вони, мабуть, мають занадто негативне забарвлення для цього випадку.

Answer (score 1):

Оскільки українська та російська мови досить близькі, то маю сміливість послатися на переклад цього слова на російську в словнику [Мультитран](//www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=Creep&l1=1):

> <…>
>
> амер.: придурок (*Daisy*********); псих (*Daisy*********); отморозок (*Daisy*********); мерзопакостный тип (*Val_Ships*); чмо (*Val_Ships*); ублюдок (*Val_Ships*); мразь (a detestable person *Val_Ships*)
>
> <…>

Саме тут є безліч варіантів. На мою думку, найбільше підходить варіант ***псих***. По суті, і *creep* i *weirdo* близькі за значенням, але щоб не повторюватися, то:

> Я псих *(в сенсі "не такий, як всі")*, я дивак.

Comment: Перепрошую за запізнілу реакцію, але українська мова та московський язик не є близькими мовами, про що свідчить, наприклад, відсутність в українській мові наведених вами московських слів *«отморозок»*, *«чмо»* та *«ублюдок»*, цілком характерних для московського язика.

Comment: @bytebuster ваше твердження також не досить обґрунтоване. Все залежить від того, які мови вважати "близькими". Ваша позиція і позиція дописувачки залежать від поняттєвого ґрунту (того, що ви вкладаєте у поняття "близька мова"), і я би не сказав, що ваша позиція більш авторитетна, аніж позиція дописувачки в цьому разі. Я також проти міфів, що наші дві мови найближчі одна до одної, але казати, що вони "не є близькими", враховуючи історію формування одної й іншої, а також їхню належність до одної мовної ґрупи, м'яко кажучи, дивно.

Answer (score 1):

Знайшов цікавить і досить непоганий [переклад](https://lyricstranslate.com/ru/creep-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA.html) цих рядків:

> Та я - слимак!.. 
>   Дивакуватий я є...
>
> Що ж я, в біса, тут роблю?
>
> Це ж не моє...

Щоправда, трішки мені не подобається переклад "слимак", тому я вирішив пошукати ще можливі варіанти, і [тут](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/creep?page=1) серед них є такі: [плазун](http://sum.in.ua/s/plazun), [гад](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghad) (непоганий варіант), [монстр](http://sum.in.ua/s/monstr) (також можливий варіант), [покидьок](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokydjky) (на мою думку, найкращий варіант перекладу).

Answer (score 1):

Менi здається, що, в контекстi змiсту цього вiчного хiта, *creep* значить "хробак". В переносному розумiннi: звичайна, нiчим не примiтна людина, яких є мiльйони. До всього, це людина з цiлою купою комплексiв, знову ж, властивою пересiчнiй бiльшостi людства.

Comment: Мабуть, приблизно так воно і є. Статті, де учасники гурту висловлюються про цю пісню: [Cristi Kempf «The Radiohead Vision Creeps Onto Airwaves»](http://www.greenplastic.com/coldstorage/articles/chicagosun.html), [Jim Sullivan «‘Creep’ Stumbles Onto Fame»](//books.google.com/books?id=OwVrDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT21&dq=%22creep+stumbles+onto+fame%22).

Answer (score 1):

Мені здається, треба не забувати, що це пісня, вірш, отже значення необов'язково мають перекладатися через словникові варіанти перекладу.

Мушу зрозуміти, що таке creep:

1. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/creep):

> an unpleasant or obnoxious person — неприємна або огидна людина

2. [urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=creep):

> someone who's personality or overall behaviour is strange or weird. — хтось, чия особистість або поведінка дивна або дивакувата.

Отже, в принципі, тут weirdo і creep можуть взагалі бути синонімами, які через різні відтінки передають самопочуття "ліричного героя" як когось дивного, дивакуватого, такого, якого обходять.

Більшість відповідей (або й усі) оминала цікаве українське слово

### нікчема

Можливий варіант перекладу такий:

> Та я — нікче-ема, я — дива-ак
>
> Що я забу-ув тут?
>
> Я н**е** з цього сві-іту

Не менш відповідними з огляду на контекст видаються варіанти "страхопуд" або "страшило" з [цієї відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6229/240), а також "слимак" з [цієї](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5125/240), хробак з [цієї](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6248/240) тощо (адже порівнняня йде з незрівнянною красою когось, ким захоплюється "ліричний герой" цієї пісні, отже всі переклади, що означають непривабливість, сірість мають право на існування).

Трохи менш відповідними видаються варіанти "псих" (адже це на сьогодні має активніше, іноді аґресивне, а іноді навіть позитивне забарвлення), "паскудник", "поганець", "покидьок" (адже зрештою ми не знаємо, як до себе ставиться "ліричний герой", лиш знаємо, що він заздрить тому, кого обожнює).

Answer (score 1):

Власне, creep тут МОТОРОШНИЙ, і дуже хочу згадати тут молодіжний узус, що зараз засвоїв англицизм. Молодь каже "це якось кріпово" в значенні "це страшнувато, стрьомно, моторошно". Наприклад, в соцмережах викладають контент, що викликає легке відчуття "мурашок", і підписують його "кріпово".

Додаю тут переклад МОТОРОШНО з одного джерела:

https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/ukrainian-word-for-8fd07900962f755baeee5a37194ab56030e1b001.html

Answer (score -2):

Це можна перекласти як "страхопуд", або "страшило". Перше слово досить таки рідковживане в розмовній мові, але доречне в цій ситуації.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].